# Laravel conditional binding at runtime

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a case where I have two different email providers for transactional emails (because one is unreliable). To know which provider I am using, I have a DB flag which controls which provider is to be used. I would also like to code to an interface so that I don't have to repeat too much code.

Is it possible in Laravel to use a Service Provider to check the provider setting in the DB before returning the binding for the emailing interface? If not, is it possible to bind an interface to an implementation in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to have a service provider, which fetches a value from the db trough a model and then, based on some conditions, chooses to start one over the other mailer.

```
//Your loaded emailProvider
private $emailProvider = null;

public function boot()
{
    $this->emailProvider->boot();
}


public function register()
{
    $user = User::find(3);
    //Split email in [0] someusername and [1] somedomain
    $emailArray = explode('@',$user->email);
    $domain = $emailArray[1];
    switch($domain)
    {
        case 'someProvider.com':
            $this->emailProvider = new SomeProviderEmailServiceProvider(app());
        break;
        default:
            $this->emailProvider = new DefaultEmailServiceProvider(app());
    }
    $this->emailProvider->register();
}
```

This way you can easily add, remove or update your 'special cases', in stead of doing a lot of wizardry.